# callback in callback with waterfall in nodejs

Tags: node.js, callback, mongoose, waterfall

I am using MEAN (Mongo Express Angulars NodeJs) for a project. The problem is I have to add one extra attribute to data received from query object. And make new data array with exactly old data array but have one extra attribute. I know how to add attribute and pass them into callback using waterfall model, as I am using multiple callback functions and for loops I am not able to get expected result.

code:

```
var fetchRevenue = function(restaurantArray, type, startDate, endDate, fn) {
_.forEach(restaurantArray, function(rest) {
    fetchDateWiseReport(new Date('07/10/2015'), new Date('07/16/2015'), rest._id, type, function(orders) {
          var newOrders = [];
      async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
          if(orders && orders.length > 0){
            async.forEach(orders, function(order) {
              getSellingPriceOfItems(order.orders, function(sp) {
              order.sp = sp;
              newOrders.push(order);
              if (newOrders.length === orders.length)
                callback(null, newOrders);
            });
              }); 
             } else {
            newOrders.push([]);
          }        
        },
        function(newOrders, callback) {
            var restArr = []
          //get sum of all orders of each restaurant and add into restArr
          callback(null, restArr);

        },
        function(restArr, callback) {
          callback(null, newOrders);
        }
      ], function(err, result) {
        fn(result);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

where my functions:

1. fetchDateWiseReport = fetches restaurant record for given date and send result in callback
2. getSellingPriceOfItems = query to item model find price for each item and return selling price of given array and send result in callback.
   my complete code including all functions is [here](https://gist.github.com/zoyaH/cbb99bcace70da441b82).
   now I want orders should be equal to newOrders with additional attibute 'sp'. But I am unable to get this. Will you suggest me something to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Use Express way to handle callback problem

in you route

```
app.get('you/route',fetchDateWiseReport(), second(),finalReturningREsult())
```

your first function will be doing first async loop function assiggn reult in req.body.firstResult and pass to second function. and so on